# Apache ECharts bar animation?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, echarts, ngx-echarts

Trying to get resize bar animation working on for the [Apache ECharts demo (Link)](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-animation-delay&lang=ts) .

[This is the Stackblitz - The chart code is in the hello component.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ms8aq3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

The chart instance is obtained from a call to this method.

```
  onChartInit(echarts) {
    this.echartsIntance = echarts;
  }
```

The `chartInit` event emitter on the chart triggers it.

```
<div
  echarts
  (chartInit)="onChartInit($event)"
  [options]="options"
  class="demo-chart"
></div>
```

And the window resize events are observed via RxJS `fromEvent`.  The `resize()` method is called in the constructor:

```
  resize() {
    fromEvent(window, 'resize')
      .pipe(debounceTime(200))
      .subscribe((e) => {
        console.log('RESIZE');
        if (this.echartsIntance) {
          this.echartsIntance.resize();
        }
      });
  }
```

When the window resizes the chart bars should animate however the animation does not occur.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the chart markup itself we have to add.

```
[autoResize]="false"
```

And the `resize` method must be configured.  Here's an example:

```
this.echartsIntance.resize({
  animation: {
     duration: 1500,
     easing: 'elasticOut',
   },
});
```

[This is a new working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cdbwbt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts).